# remove field and add new field to the mapping in elastic search index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I made a mistake at the time of first index creation for one field. Instead of "integer" data type mistakenly I assigned as "string" for the field "rating". But the data stored in the field was integer only. When I'm trying to calculate the average rating aggregation it was throwing an error because of the string data type.

1. Is there a way to change the data type of the field with out reindexing?
2. If not possible without reindex, how can I remove the rating field and add a rating field with "integer" data type?

Help me on this issue to resolve.

**Update**

Deleted the type in the index by using below command

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9300/feedbacks_16/responses'
```

Deleted the type and created the type with the same name and changed the data type for my rating field and re indexed the entire data. Everything goes fine until reindexing. But the avg query not working. 
Below is the error I'm getting :

```
{ "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[2NsGsPYLR2eP9p2zYSnKGQ][feedbacks-16][0]: ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]}{[2NsGsPYLR2eP9p2zYSnKGQ][feedbacks_16][1]: ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]}{[pcwXn3X-TceUO0ub29ZFgA][feedbacks_16][2]: RemoteTransportException[[tsles02][inet[/localhost:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: ClassCastException; }{[pcwXn3X-TceUO0ub29ZFgA][feedbacks_16][3]: RemoteTransportException[[tsles02][inet[/localhost:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: ClassCastException; }{[2NsGsPYLR2eP9p2zYSnKGQ][feedbacks_16][4]: ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]}]", "status": 500 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Aside from a few exceptions, a mapping [cannot be updated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings). There are some exceptions:

- you can add new properties
- you can promote a simple field to a multi-field
- you can disable `doc_values` (but not enable them)
- you can update the `ignore_above` parameter

So if you wish to transform your `rating` field from string to integer without recreating a new index, the only solution you have is to create a sub-field (e.g. called `rating.int`) of type `integer`.

Note that you'll still have to reindex your data in order to populate that new sub-field, though. However, if you do so, you'd be much better off simply re-creating a clean index from scratch and re-populating it.

Comment: For the benefit of others with the same issue, can you tell which approach you've taken (or are going to take)?

Comment: I deleted the type in the index and re created the mapping for the type in that index. I updated my question. I have multiple types in the index. So I deleted only one type and recreated that index. Is that causing the error?

Comment: In order to delete a mapping type you need to do it like this: `curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9300/feedbacks_16/_mapping/responses'`, i.e. you've forgotten `/_mapping/` in the path. Most certainly, your type was not deleted correctly and now your mapping contains mixed integer and string data (hint: class cast exception between `IndexNumericFieldData` and  `PagedBytesIndexFieldData`).

Answer (score 1):

1) You can change data type of field without reindexing but the problem is that It wont affect your data i.e `rating` field will remain `string` as documents are stored in `immutable segments` but newly added field will be `integer` but again that wont solve your problem

2) You could delete all documents from your current index and then change the mapping with `PUT API` like this

```
$ curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_mapping?ignore_conflicts=true' -d 
'{
  "your_type": {
    "properties": {
      "rating": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

and then reindex

but better would be to create new index with above mapping and [reindex with zero downtime](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime)