# SearchKick(Elastic Search) freshly reindex specific record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

Hi I have one issue for reindexing record which was reindexed earlier with attribute having different datatype.

eg: User 1 having date_of_birth as string while reindex and now i want to reindex that user with datetime column its crashing with error

```
"MapperParsingException[failed to parse [dob]]; nested: NumberFormatException"
```

Tried deleting the index for the record with following and reindex but did not worked.

```
User.searchkick_index.remove(user)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the type of an existing field, once it's created [there are only a few changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013228/remove-field-and-add-new-field-to-the-mapping-in-elastic-search-index/34013359#34013359) that are allowed. The most surefire way is to wipe your index and recreate it from scratch with the proper mapping.

A temporary alternate solution is to rename your field so a new one with the new `date` type will be created.

Comment: Problem is that i the field creation is not under our control. These are dynamic fields for reindex which can be added by user.

Comment: Then your only option is to wipe out your index, recreate it with the proper mappings and re-index your existing data.

Comment: That's terrible, for only one record whole reindex.

Comment: Elasticsearch is not a magic wand :-) It might be only one record, but you need to be in control of the field types you're creating. If you don't, you land in situation such as this one. Once a field is created with a given type [there are very few options to change its type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013228/remove-field-and-add-new-field-to-the-mapping-in-elastic-search-index/34013359#34013359).

Comment: I liked the concept for having seperate fields for datatypes eg: "rating.int".
Will try this, but will need lot change in the code. Thanks for the link and suggestion.

Comment: Multi-fields is indeed one way to solve this, but without proper field curation, it can get out of control pretty quickly, too. Definitely worth investigating.